# TransformBroadcaster and Gazebo plugins

Tags: differential-drive, ros-fuerte, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I have been wanting to get various Gazebo plugins working with ROS using SDF format, starting with Differential Drive plugin. I had some small success getting Twist messages to change joint states, but now I want to get odometry working. I have just pieced together what I could from erratic_gazebo_plugins and the DRCSim plugins.

[DiffDriveROSPlugin.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/TheLegace/ales_robot/src/ee0547cf6f355456174b583fc493248d0bf6ef66/ales_msgs/src/DiffDriveROSPlugin.cpp?at=default)

`this->transformBroadcaster = new tf::TransformBroadcaster();`

Any time I want to declare a TransformBroadcaster type I get this error:

gazebo: symbol lookup error:

> /home/thelegace/fuerte_workspace/ales_robot/ales_msgs/lib/libDiffDriveROSPlugin.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZN2tf20TransformBroadcasterC1Ev

If I comment out the transform broadcaster instantiation my plugin loads fine.
The [pioneer2dx](https://bitbucket.org/TheLegace/ales_robot/src/ee0547cf6f355456174b583fc493248d0bf6ef66/ales_description/models/pioneer2dx/model-1_3.sdf?at=default) model file.

Please let know if there any issue with the code or anything else that I am doing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1435/transformbroadcaster-and-gazebo-plugins/) by [Vaibhav Kapoor](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/212/vaibhav-kapoor/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-17**:
This seems to be a a linker error, I think. Are you linking the tf library in CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Undefined symbol errors usually indicates that a library cannot be found, or an incorrect library is used.

In your case I believe Gazebo will have to find a library for `tf`. Check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on 2014-10-13**:
hey , I am getting the same error . I have integrated gazebo with ros using ros enabled model plugin tutorial. so do I need to use roscreate-pkg pakage-name roscpp tf in order to make the dependency to tf ? . Thanks!